# Previously Playing Music Doesn't Stops On Button Press.

Tags: imagebutton

I'm an absolute novice in programming, dared to start with Android Programming lately. Added 4 Image Buttons, every button plays a unique tune and displays a unique message; but the problem is that if I press another button after clicking one, the previous music continues to play while the present one is still on, in short both the music continue to run. If I play four of the buttons one after another, four different tunes play altogether. Couldn't find a way out. Please help, if possible in an elaborate manner. Another question, have I created the coding too much complicated?

```
package com.example.imagesonic;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        try{


       ImageButton ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
       final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muzikone);

        ib1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()  {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FIRST MUSIC!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mp1.start();

            }    


        });


        ImageButton ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muziktwo);

         ib2.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SECOND MUSIC!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mp2.start();

            }    


        });



         ImageButton ib3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
         final MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muzikthree);

          ib3.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "THIRD MUSIC!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 mp3.start();

            }    


        });


          ImageButton ib4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
          final MediaPlayer mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muzikfour);

           ib4.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FOURTH MUSIC!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ImageButton ib4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
                ib4.setImageResource(R.drawable.naomitan);  
                 mp4.start();

            }    


        });

    }catch(Exception e) {

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your application working in such a manner that once one song plays, all the other songs will stop playing, you have to use a service and implement the [Android Audio manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html) for callbacks that you can then control your MediaPlayer instances to stop playing music if another AudioManger instance is playing music.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) is some great documentation that Google provides on instructions for implementing this. It is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your precious time to place your precious advice for a novice like me. I shall try to study that asap and revert to you, if I need any advice. Hope you'll understand. Take Care.

Comment: awesome, let me know if you need any help!